# Not able to install BalenaEtcher on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to install BalenaEtcher on ubuntu 20.04 but getting "BalenaEtcher repository not found 502 bad gateway"

Tried these commands:
`echo "deb https://deb.etcher.io stable etcher" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install balena-etcher-electron`

Comment: Clear, simple instructions for installing Etcher are at https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this worked for me

```
curl -1sLf \
   'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/setup.deb.sh' \
   | sudo -E bash
```

then,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install balena-etcher-electron
```

ref: https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64

Comment: helpful, thank you. where is the source?

Comment: @dia here i found the answer. https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64

Comment: lovely, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm not telling you what to do, but why don't you run balenaEtcher via Appimage?

You will probably need balenaEtcher only occasionally and the Appimage works really well. You can firejail it if you want to. If you add [Appimagelauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher), then the Appimages integrate really well with the desktop. You can search them via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> or start them via launcher.

You don't need to install a `.deb` file.  It is perhaps less risky to use the Appimage. Just a thought...

Comment: The Appimage works really good for me also. Just download  https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.7.9/balena-etcher-electron-1.7.9-linux-x64.zip?d_id=e7f87540-a6ee-4b35-828e-da044bda2299R , unzip and click