# How to remove balena etcher to fix "failed to fetch" error during "sudo apt update" on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates, ppa

I received the following error while updating Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt update`.

```sh
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  402  Payment Required [IP: 18.160.249.56 443]
E: The repository 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
```

I have looked into what is necessary and it seems that the ppa (`https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu`) used by balena etcher is no longer signed. However, I was not sure of what exactly will fix this.

This question is to help anyone who comes across a similar situation. Basically, what I am looking forward to is the exact set of steps that will resolve this issue.

> **Generic problem statement**: You have some ppa's on your system and for some reason they could be stale and that is effectively blocking the `sudo apt update` process. What do you need to fix this?

**Note**: This question was originally opened on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674306) and then moved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The problem here is with a stale `ppa`. There are a few ways to approach this problem, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

#### Step(s) Necessary to remediate the original error

Run the following command. Please note that since the `ppa` in question here is not of the form `https://ppa.launchpad.net/x/y/ppa/ubuntu`, we cannot straight away use the syntax `ppa:x/y` as suggested by these solutions: [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/853549), [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/a/173199/853549), [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/a/313/853549).

> **Important**: See [this suggestion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2487015&s=49ee6c9e98fc5302ef8180bb7226f545&p=14143742#post14143742), which ultimately worked for me.

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu
```

Once you run this, run the following two commands and you should not find anything as shown in **A** and **B** below.

```sh
# this should return empty result (as this file must no-longer exist)
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list

# this should show the default repository for balena (not the ppa)
apt policy | grep "balena"
```

Once you have verified this, run:

```sh
sudo apt update
```

If you need to remove any GPG security keys alongside, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107177/how-can-i-remove-gpg-key-that-i-added-using-apt-key-add/107189#107189). [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/846877/853549) will help in determining the key. And follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/173209/853549) to remove it, if necessary.

```sh
# list the trusted keys
sudo apt-key list
# remove the key
sudo apt-key del KEY_ID
```

And `sudo apt update` should be working now!

---

> **NOTE**:
>
> You need to pay attention to two things here to fix this: **A** and **B** below.

#### A: ppa-source-list

When a ppa is added, a ppa-specific file is created under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

For `balen-etcher`, there was the following file (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list`).

```sh
# Source: balena
# Site: https://github.com/balena-io/etcher
# Repository: balena / etcher
# Description: Flash OS images to SD cards & USB drives, safely and easily.


deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/balena-etcher-archive-keyring.gpg] https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main

deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/balena-etcher-archive-keyring.gpg] https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
```

According to [this stack-exchange solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/173209/853549) you could also delete this ppa specific file to revert to factory settings (as it was before adding the ppa).

If the ppa is successfully removed the above mentioned ppa-source-list file will cease to exist.

#### B: apt-policy

Next inspect the apt-policy and search for `balena` there.

```sh
apt policy | grep "balena"
```

This returned, in my case:

```sh
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

 500 https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release o=cloudsmith/balena/etcher,a=focal,n=focal,c=main,b=i386
 500 https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=cloudsmith/balena/etcher,a=focal,n=focal,c=main,b=amd64
```

#### What is a PPA?

Quoting this [source](https://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/).

> PPA stands for Personal Package Archive. It provides a way to easily
> install application which can not be found in the Ubuntu official
> repository on Ubuntu (since the Ubuntu official repo takes a
> conservative approach to updates and number of applications it
> includes in its official repository with focus on stability over
> latest and greatest packages). PPA is one of the coolest things about
> Ubuntu. It creates an avenue for developers, packagers and even users
> to create their own personal repositories and include their packages
> which can easily be added and installed on Ubuntu.

#### References

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)
- [How to list and remove PPA repository on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-list-and-remove-ppa-repository-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux)
- [Big Brovar: How to Safely Remove PPA Repository from Ubuntu](https://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/)
- [Not able to install balena-etcher on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417784/not-able-to-install-balenaetcher-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [Official install instruction for ubuntu/Debian from GitHub repository](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64)